# AWS Lambda log - read as a string

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda which uses some modules which write to the stdout.
These appear in the Lambda logs - however I need to be able to read and parse the stdout after the module is executed within the same lambda.

Is this possible with the Logger library?  Note that I would like to read the log from the current execution only.

```
import os
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Do Stuff
    log = logger.get_log()# read the log into a variable???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What "AWS Logger Library" are you referring to? The code in your question is using the standard [Python logging library](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html), not anything AWS specific. You certainly can't read previous Lambda invocation logs using that library.

You would need to use the [AWS SDK for Python](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#client) (Boto3) to read those logs out of CloudWatch.

You could also configure CloudWatch to [stream the log data to another Lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295838/cloudwatch-logs-stream-to-lambda-python).

Comment: I want to read the current execution lambda log (not any previous execution).

Comment: By default the log is just going to STDOUT so it isn't going to be persisted anywhere inside the Lambda function's context. I if you want to persist it temporarily you would need to configure the logger to write the log to `/tmp` in addition to STDOUT.